# When does recursion stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

To stop the recursion we must provide an base. Apart from providing the base, when does a recursion stops. Does it stops when it stops calling itself again?.

```
def func(x):
    n=[]
    for i in n:
        func(x)
```

Here, does it call the function or does nothing. Does recursion stop at scenario like this and starts backtracking?

Comment: This function won't have any recursion because n is an empty list; you never enter the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th line in your code does not get executed as the list n contains no elements. Hence `func`gets terminated without any recursion.

Comment: So in any recursion function,  if the list becomes empty, it does not execute itself again and starts calling previously stacked functions?In depth first search, the leaf node does not contain child nodes, hence the adjaceny list becomes empty. So is it the reason it starts backtracking to its previous nodes?

Comment: Yes, if your function contains a list and if it becomes empty then the condition would become false and recursion will stop. It depends on your base-case condition. If the funcion terminates when there is no element in the list, then the recursion would stop. ``` def func(x):
    n=[4]
    for i in n:
        func(x) ``` Just showing you an example of infinite recursion here

Comment: Thanks a lot. Iam a noob in recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Since `n` is empty, the `for` loop will do nothing, and `func` will just terminate without performing any recursion.

Comment: So in any recursion function,  if the list becomes empty, it does not execute itself again and starts calling previously stacked functions?. In depth first search, the leaf node does not contain child nodes, hence the adjaceny list becomes empty. So is it the reason it starts backtracking to its previous nodes?

Comment: Internally, recursion works based on stack and not dfs. Subsequent function calls are appended to the top of the stack, when a function's base case is reached, it returns the value to the function which called it. In this way the very first function call would be present at the bottom of the stack and would give us our final result.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian. Yes iam studying DFS using recursion method. AdjacencyList is empty for the leaf node. I wanted to clear the doubt regarding when recursion stops. I read that when it reaches the base case it stops and returns the value to previous function in the stack.